# jQuery JavaScript making a footer or other element disappear if the page is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I've seen a trend where a fixed/absolute element will automatically hide itself from the view if the browser is less than a certain size, recently I've come across a client who wishes to have such a thing on a couple elements on there page. But I'm not sure how to approach that. Whats the best way to handle this type of action like what would I need to bind to, or what event do I have to be mindful of to say if the window is less than x wide or z tall hide this element and that element. The hiding part I can handle through a nice animation of sorts but just don't know which event to be mindful of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about http://api.jquery.com/resize/